# Django Rest API relationship no such column

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to get recipes from my django rest api but now I dont know how to get a recipe with the ingredients. I tried the following:

### My models.py:

```
class Ingredients(models.Model):
    ingredientid = models.AutoField(db_column='IngredientID', primary_key=True, blank=True)
    recipeid = models.ForeignKey('Recipe', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='RecipeID', blank=True, null=True, related_name='+')
    amount = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=100)
    unit = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=100)
    unit2 = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=100)
    ingredient = models.CharField(db_column='Ingredient', blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Ingredients'

class Recipe(models.Model):
    recipeid = models.AutoField(db_column='RecipeID', primary_key=True, blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    title = models.CharField(db_column='Title', blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)  # Field name made lowercase.
    preperation = models.TextField(db_column='Preperation', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    images = models.CharField(db_column='Images', blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)  # Field name made lowercase.
    ingredients = models.ForeignKey(Ingredients, related_name='ingredients', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Recipes'
```

### My serializer.py:

```
class IngredientsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredients
        fields = '__all__'

class FullRecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ingredients = IngredientsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ['recipeid','title','images', 'preperation', 'ingredients']
```

### And my view:

```
class FullRecipesView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = FullRecipeSerializer
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]
    queryset = Recipe.objects.all()
```

In the view, I am not sure if the queryset is right. But now I get the error:

```
OperationalError at /api/full-recipes
no such column: Recipes.ingredients_id
```

And I think its because I never defined that the relationship is the recipeid but I don't know where I can do it.

I hope you can help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why `IngredientsSerializer(many=True)`? It's a foreign key, so you can assign only one of them

Comment: To be honest I don't completely understand what this does but this is not why the error occurs